# ReactJS add comma to price only on focus/change

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What I trying to achieve is add `comma` to number `(price format)` only when user `foucs` and also `change`, when user `blur` I want to display normal without comma. So what I tried so far is:

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      price: ''
    };
  }

  price = (v) => {
    return v.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }


  handleBlur = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      price: this.state.value
    })
  }

  handleFocus = (e) => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      price: this.price(v)
    })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      price: v /*this.price(v)*/,
      value: v
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( < div className = "Login" > <
      br / >
      <
      input type = "text"
      value = {
        this.state.price
      }
      onBlur = {
        this.handleBlur
      }
      onFocus = {
        this.handleFocus
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      /> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Login name = "Login" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

**Problems:**

1. Replace and regex not working correct if I use it on `change`, it return like this: `2,5,0,0,0,0,0,000`.

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: '',
      price: ''
    };
  }

  price = (v) => {
    return v.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }


  handleBlur = (e) => {
    this.setState({
      price: this.state.value
    })
  }

  handleFocus = (e) => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      price: this.price(v)
    })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    const v = e.target.value;
    this.setState({
      price: this.price(v),
      value: v
    })
  }

  render() {
    return ( < div className = "Login" > <
      br / >
      <
      input type = "text"
      value = {
        this.state.price
      }
      onBlur = {
        this.handleBlur
      }
      onFocus = {
        this.handleFocus
      }
      onChange = {
        this.handleChange
      }
      /> < /
      div >
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  Login name = "Login" / > ,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```

2. And if user blur it, value still have comma.

So what I want is type numbers, it add comma and separate as price format, then if blur, remove comma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish between `value` that is always without any commas and formatted `price` with the commas. Also, it's recommended to save only 1 source of truth in the state, e.g. `value` and compute the other one when needed (note that "when needed" is another state, e.g. `isFocus`).

An example solution using the above principles:

```js
class Login extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      value: '',
      isFocus: true
    }
  }
  
  price = () => this.state.isFocus
    ? this.state.value.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")
    : this.state.value
    
  handleBlur = (e) => this.setState({isFocus: false})
  handleFocus = (e) => this.setState({isFocus: true})
  handleChange = (e) => this.setState({value: e.target.value.replace(/,/g, "")})

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Login">
        <br />
        <input 
          type="text"
          value={this.price()}
          onBlur={this.handleBlur}
          onFocus={this.handleFocus}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Login />, document.getElementById('container'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: const handleChange = e => {
    let data = e.target.value;
    let convertedData = data.replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    setinput(convertedData);
    formik.setFieldValue("estimated_gross_payroll", convertedData);
  };            can you tell me where i am wrong i am calling this on change

Comment: @PrateekPareek this is an answer to a question from 2019 and when I run the snippet it still works as requested in the original question => if you have a different question that includes formik, please ask a new question instead of a comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could use such a function for the comma formatted display:

```
const format = (num)=>{
  numArray = num.toString().split('').reverse();
  for(let i = 3; i < numArray.length; i+=4){
    numArray.splice(i, 0, ',');
    }
  return numArray.reverse().join("");
}
```

Then just prompt a different display or value between raw number and formatted number when you control the state.

Comment: how would this solve either of the 2 problems in the question, that the input already contains commas (e.g. `format('1,2345')`)?